# How to upload data from raspberry pi to MySQL, geting errors

Tags: python, pi-2, mysql

Basically I am trying to upload the data collected from my raspberry pi to MySQL, I have a table called DHT_data with columns 'datetime' using data type timestamp, 'temp' using data type numeric, 'hum' using data type numeric as well. However using my Python script shown below I keep getting errors like indentation error or syntax error. I am currently new to programming so I don't really know what's the problem. Would appreciate any help in finding the solution or rectifying any errors with the script since I am not sure if it works yet

```
import time
import Adafruit_DHT
import MySQLdb
import sys
from time import sleep

DHTpin = 4

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "dmitiot", "IOTassignmentBobo")
    curs = db.cursor()
    print("Successfully connected to database!")
    except:
    print("Error connecting to mySQL database")
    update = True
    while update:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, DHTpin)
    if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
    hum = round(humidity)
    temp = round(temperature, 1)
    print('Temp:{:.1f}C'.format(temp))
    print('Hum:{:.1f}'.format(hum))

    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO DHT_data(datetime,temp,hum) 
    VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,temp,hum)""")
    print("Inserted Record")
    db.commit()
    sleep(5)
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    update = False
    curs.close()
    db.close()
```

Comment: Welcome. When you have a code problem, you should always copy the full error message as well as the code. The error message gives you information about exactly where the error is and how to fix it; see [this page](https://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-inflammation/07-errors/) for some tips.

Comment: your code is incorrectly indented. .... it is a python error that has nothing to do with MySQL .... you need to read the basics of python programming

Comment: this question has nothing to do with RPi and should be closed

Comment: basically, an indentation error occurs when you either don't indent (4 spaces) after a ":" or when you don't stop indenting. Indentation in Python indicates a group of commands that should all be run when the conditional is true or inside a loop. This may help https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: Note to moderators: OP is having cross domain conceptual issues in Raspberry Pi context. Instead of punishing OP, it is more helpful to assist OP in breaking down problem to identify correct resources for finding help (i.e., Python misuse leads to MySQL error)

Comment: @OyaMist, this isn't a punishment in any way. It's simply people suggesting that this site isn't the best one for the question (as it's primarily a programming question rather than a Pi problem; the problem would be unchanged elsewhere). That said I voted as 'unclear' rather than 'off-topic' but only the final vote affected the reason displayed here. Unfortunately the Q&A format isn't well equipped for problems like this where there are several issues to address such as indentation in Python. As Steve points out, reviewing the documentation might be more helpful to the OP.

Comment: @Aurora, yes, unclear indeed. I wish we had a better way ease the journey into the languages Tower of Babel--I myself missed the indentation issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL insert statement is not inserting the temperature and humidity values. In the VALUES clause, the **temp** and **hum** variables are not being replaced by their values. See [documentation for Python string concatenation](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

One way to do this is:

```
sqlinsert="INSERT INTO DHT_data9datetime,temp,hum) "
sqlvalues="VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," + str(temp) + "," + str(hum) + ")"
curs.execute(sqlinsert + sqlvalues)
```

NOTE: [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) is a MySQL variable that resolves to the current time

Comment: Shouldn't "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" be treated similarly to temp and hum?

Comment: Updated answer with link to MySQL documentation